# How do I deploy to a Server?

Tags: configuration, appconkit

I have created an App with the AppConKit 3 and tested it locally on my Computer, running from the AppConDeveloper. Now i'd like to deploy it to a tomcat server. How do I do that? I've the Eclipse Java Perspective open.

Answer (score 2):

If you are that far, it's fairly simple. 
right click on your _server project and select "Export"-> "Export..." 
In the new window, unfold "Web" and select "War" File 
(If you have the Java EE perspective open, your can directly select Export->War)
Set the Destination of the War file accordingly (ideally, set the name to Appname.war, not Appname_server.war) and click Finish.

All you have left to do is to deploy this .war to your Java Application Server. If you have a tomcat server, go to `http://YourServerIp:8080/manager/html/` (you will need a username & password) and find the section at the bottom of the page that says "WAR file to deploy". Click on Browser and locate the saved war above. Click on Upload.
When your upload is through, you can reach your server at `http://YourServerIp:8080/Warfilename` .